# What's the usage of empty class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

We can create an empty class using pass statement in Python.

```
# An empty class 
class Test: 
    pass
```

The question here is **why we need empty classes?**

Or do not know under what circumstances we are suppose to use an empty class.

I can't image the usage in daily  development. Could anyone give a demonstration and explanation?

Comment: Where do you see a class like this? How is it used there?

Comment: hope this link will help you to understand : https://www.quora.com/Why-would-you-want-to-have-an-empty-class-in-Python

Comment: While empty classes are sometimes useful, you shouldn't assume that something has to be useful because it's possible. I can put a shoe in a blender. What's the use of that?

Comment: The "dash.no_update" construct has an implementation that involves an empty class.   Why would they do that?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new class, you are creating a new type. This newly created type may have some properties, or may not. These properties allow to hold data, methods etc.

Empty class that doesn't inherit any base class would be useful as placeholder.

```
class ServiceWrapper(object):
    pass

def sendMessage(svc:ServiceWrapper):
    #do something
    #pass
```

On the other hand, empty classes that inherit other classes is a very common pattern. Specially when defining user exceptions.

```
class Networkerror(RuntimeError):
    pass

try:
    raise Networkerror()
except Networkerror:
    #do something
    #pass
```

Also recently, the python `collections.abc` allows creating interface like functionalities.

```
class ServiceWrapper(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def send(self):...

def sendMessage(svc:ServiceWrapper):
    svc.send()
    #pass
```